# Implicity of web page structure in Schema.org

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

After reading thousand of posts, questions, blog articles and opinions, I'm still a bit confused about how to markup a web page with microdata. If the main purpose of microdata is to help search engine to better understand the content of a web page (and web page is assumed implicitly), is it correct to start with itemtype Webpage in the body element, and then continue  to markup the rest of nested elements defining which is the main entity, or is it better to start with an itemtype that is ideally the main topic of the web page and associate properties at the top level, or is better to have different itemtype at the top level (i.e. webpage, blog post and main topic of the page)?

An example will explain better my question: if I have to markup a webpage that contains a blog post about a specific topic (let's say about wireless technology), what should be the item at the top level? Should be webpage, blogposting, or wireless technology?

Comment: *"[...] Every web page is implicitly assumed to be declared to be of type WebPage [...]"*. [Source](https://schema.org/WebPage).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen that is what is creating confusion, if every web page is implicitly a web page, when using type WebPage, what you're actually declaring?  that your web page main topic is about another web page?

Answer (score 5):

#### The more the better (with exceptions)

When it comes to structured data, the guideline should be, in the typical case: **the more the better**. If you provide more structured data (i.e., you make things explicit instead of keeping them implicit), the chance is higher that a consumer finds something it can make use of.

Reasons not to follow this guideline might include:

- You know exactly which consumers you want to support, and what they look for, and you don’t care about other (e.g., unknown or new) consumers.
- You know that a consumer is bugged in a way that it can’t cope with certain structures.
- You need to save as many characters as possible (bandwith/performance).
- It’s too complex/expensive to provide additional structured data.
- The structured data is most likely useless to any conceivable consumer.
- …

#### What `WebPage` offers

So unless you have a reason not to, it’s probably a good idea to provide the [`WebPage` type](http://schema.org/WebPage) … *if* you can provide possibly interesting data. For example:

- It allows you to provide different URIs for the page and the thing(s) on the page, or what the page represents, like a person, a building, etc. (see [why this can be useful](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) and [a slightly more technical answer with details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669)).
- [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) allows you to connect items which might otherwise be top-level items, for which it wouldn’t necessarily be clear in which relation they are.
- [`isPartOf`](http://schema.org/isPartOf) allows you to make this `WebPage` part of something else (e.g., of the website if you provide a [`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite) item, or of a [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage)).
- You have breadcrumbs on the page: use [`breadcrumb`](http://schema.org/breadcrumb) to make clear that they represent the breadcrumbs for this page.
- You provide accessibility information: use [`accessibilityAPI`](http://schema.org/accessibilityAPI), [`accessibilityControl`](http://schema.org/accessibilityControl), [`accessibilityFeature`](http://schema.org/accessibilityFeature), [`accessibilityHazard`](http://schema.org/accessibilityHazard)
- The [`author`](http://schema.org/author)/[`contributor`](http://schema.org/contributor)/[`copyrightHolder`](http://schema.org/copyrightHolder)/[`editor`](http://schema.org/editor)/[`funder`](http://schema.org/funder)/etc. of the page is different from the `author`/… of e.g. the page’s main content.
- The page has a different [`license`](http://schema.org/license) than some of the parts included in the page.
- You provide actions that can be done on/with the page: use [`potentialAction`](http://schema.org/potentialAction).
- …

Of course it also allows you to use [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity), but if this were the only thing you need the `WebPage` item for, you could as well use the inverse property [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage).

#### More specific `WebPage` types

And the same is true for the more specific types, which give additional signals:

- [`AboutPage`](http://schema.org/AboutPage) if it’s a page about e.g. the site, you, or your organization.
- [`CheckoutPage`](http://schema.org/CheckoutPage) if it’s the checkout page in a web shop.
- [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) if it’s a page about multiple things (e.g., a pagination page listing blog posts, a gallery, a product category, …).
- [`ContactPage`](http://schema.org/ContactPage) if it’s the contact page.
- [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) if it’s about a single thing (e.g., a blog posting, a photograph, …).
- [`ProfilePage`](http://schema.org/ProfilePage) e.g. for user profiles.
- [`QAPage`](http://schema.org/QAPage) if it’s … well, this very page.
- [`SearchResultsPage`](http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage) for the result pages of your search function.
- …

#### Your example

Your three cases are:

```html
<!-- A - only the topic -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <span itemprop="name">wireless technology</span>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- B - the blog post + the topic -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
    <span itemprop="name">wireless technology</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- C - the web page + the blog post + the topic -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">
  <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
      <span itemprop="name">wireless technology</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A conveys: there is something with the name "wireless technology".
B conveys: there is a blog post **about** "wireless technology".
C conveys: there is a web page that **contains a single** blog post (as **main content for that page**) **about** "wireless technology".

While I wouldn’t recommend to use A, using B is perfectly fine and probably sufficient for most use cases. While C already provides more details than B (namely that the page is for a single thing, and that this thing is the blog post, and not some other item that might also be on the page), it’s probably not needed for such a simple case. But this changes as soon as you can provide more data, in which case I’d go with C.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128539/discussion-on-answer-by-unor-implicity-of-web-page-structure-in-schema-org).