# JSON-LD format for WebPage and BlogPosting

Tags: blogs, schema.org, json-ld

I have a medic weblog. My first page only has some data and top posts.

So I use this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "name": "website name",
    "description": "website  description",
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "WebPageMedic",
        "name": "my company name"
    }
}
</script>
```

Now for another page, how can I write JSON-LD format?

I try this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "name": "website name",
        "description": "website  description",
        "publisher": {
            "@type": "WebPageMedic",
            "name": "my company name"
        },
        "mainEntity":{
         "@type":"BlogPosting",
         "headline":"BlogPosting",
         "datePublished":"2015-03-09T13:08:00-07:00",
         "articleBody": "articleBody"
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I think I must write website information (`WebPage`) in all pages and then in `mainEntity` I can write `BlogPosting` and other things.

Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is an appropriate structure if you want to have a `WebPage` item for every page (which is [not necessary, but can be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40636188/1591669)).

For a page that has multiple blog posts (in which case you might want to use [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage)), you could use a [`Blog`](http://schema.org/Blog) item or an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) item as main entity. Another option is to use the [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) property. See an [example with `mainEntity ItemList`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/99106/17633).

---

Notes about your example:

- The properties of `WebPage` should be about the page, not about the site. You used "website name" and "website description". If you want to state something about your site, you can use the [`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite) type.
- There is no `WebPageMedic` type. You’ll probably want to use [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) or one of its sub-types, e.g., [`MedicalBusiness`](http://schema.org/MedicalBusiness).