# How can I add SiteNavigationElement and footer into JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I want to build JSON-LD for my homepage. In my page I have:

1. header
2. navigation (2 series)
3. sidebar (with 2 list of items)
4. one list of main items
5. footer

I try build the JSON-LD like this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
[
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    .
    .
    .
},
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "mainEntity":{
         "@type": "ItemList",
          "itemListElement":[
           {
               "@type": "BlogPosting",
               .
               .// 4- one list of main items
               .
           }
           ...
           ]
    }
    .
    .
    .
}]
</script>
```

If my structure is true,

1. how can I add `SiteNavigationElement` and sidebar content to this JSON object? Do I have to add another object or I can insert it in `WebPage`?
2. I use JSON-LD. Do I need to use Microdata too? or is JSON-LD enough?
3. I create a full sitemap-index.xml for all menu and items. Do I really need to add `SiteNavigationElement` (and another thing except `mainEntity`) in JSON-LD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Everything you can do with Microdata can also be done with JSON-LD, and vice versa. So there is no need to mix. There might be consumers that support only one syntax for certain features, though.)

You can add `SiteNavigationElement` with the [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) property to the `WebPage`:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "hasPart": 
  {
    "@type": "SiteNavigationElement"
  }
}
```

But using `SiteNavigationElement` (and the other [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) types) is [typically not useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867175/1591669), so you might want to consider omitting it.

Comment: Is the above the same as declaring it by itself? How would you single out which element is the `SiteNavigationElement`? With the `@id` pointing to the ID of the element? Thanks for all you do, I've learned a lot from your answers.

Comment: @TomUsborne: It’s not quite the same, as my snippet conveys "There is page that has a navigation", while your alternative would convey "There is a navigation" -- but if a consumer were interested in navigations, it would likely assume for the latter that it’s the navigation for the current page. -- To convey which HTML element is used for the navigation, you could use the `xpath` and/or `cssSelector` properties (but both are in Pending currently).