# Which property to use for WebPage sections?

Tags: categories, schema.org, microdata

I have pages that aren't articles and have multiple sections on the page describing different organizations/services and their information. I am defining the page as a `WebPage` since this page isn't really an article.

Which property should I use to best mark these sections on the page?

Comment: General questions about SEO techniques are on topic over at [webmasters.se]. If you'll note from the [tag:seo] tag, the scope for SEO questions here is extremely narrow.

Comment: @Will: This question doesn’t seem to be about SEO (well, it has the tag, but the question itself doesn’t ask for SEO advice). Schema.org is a vocabulary/ontology which happens to be relevant for SEO, but this is just one of many reasons for using it. I agree that [webmasters.se] is a better fit, but it should be on-topic here, too.

Comment: @unor Based on what is the "best" markup re SEO this question is best suited for wse..

Answer (score 1):

[WebPageElement](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) or one of its more specific types might be what you're looking for.

There is a [full hierarchy of types](http://schema.org/docs/full.html) that should point you in the right direction.

If you're looking to markup contact information such as email, phone etc. you might want to try [ContactPoint](http://schema.org/ContactPoint) or [PostalAddress](http://schema.org/PostalAddress).

Comment: Thanks for the response. What would be the advantage of WebPageElement over something like an "ItemList" of "itemListElement" objects in the "mainEntity" property of a WebPage?

Answer (score 1):

As @Brad [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785593/1591669), the [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) type would be the closest match for something like a "webpage section". You could [use the `hasPart` property to denote that they are parts of your `WebPage`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/95388/17633).

But I think that it’s [typically not useful to provide `WebPageElement`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867175/1591669) (or one of its child types) in the first place: don’t say something about how you structure your page, say something about the things you describe on your page.

So if you provide data about an organization, use [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization).  If you provide data about a service offered by an organization, use [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) (→ [`provider`](http://schema.org/provider) `Organization`) etc.

Use the [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) property of your `WebPage` (or one if its more specific types) to link the primary item the page is about:

- If the page is about a single organization, you could use:
  `ItemPage` `mainEntity` `Organization`.
- If the page is about multiple organizations, you could add a list:
  `CollectionPage` `mainEntity` [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList)

  (and each `Organization` would be its own list item, added via [`itemListElement`](http://schema.org/itemListElement))

(By the way, even if `Article` would be appropriate in your case, you could still use `WebPage` in addition, so it’s not either-or. In that case, the `mainEntity` of the `WebPage`, or the more specific `ItemPage`, would be the `Article` item.)