# HTML image map as SiteNavigationElement

Tags: html, schema.org, imagemap, microdata

I’m planning to use an HTML image map as a schema.org `SiteNavigationElement`.

The idea is to use the image as a venue map and as a visual aid to find local business in my area.

The code was validated through the Google Structured Data Testing Tool and everything seems to be ok.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" >
  <div itemprop="name">the name</div>
  <div itemprop="description">the description</div>
  <img itemprop="image" src="map.jpg" usemap="#map_tag"/>
  <map name="#map_tag">
    <area itemprop="url" coords="1, 2, 3, 4" href="link1.php" shape="rect" alt="alt_text1"/>
    <area itemprop="url" coords="5, 5, 7, 8" href="link2.php" shape="rect" alt="alt_text2"/>
  </map>
</div>
```

Is this a valid use for `SiteNavigationElement`?

Answer (score 0):

No, the `url` property of `SiteNavigationElement` is for the URI of the navigation (it’s unlikely to have one), not for the URLs of the links the navigation contains. See [my answer to "What is the correct use of schema.org SiteNavigationElement?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12491102/1591669).

Apart from that, it seems to be appropriate. However (to be sure, as you are only using example text), the `name` should give the name (and the `description` the description) of the navigation itself, not of the page etc.

(Note that it’s typically not very useful to use these [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) types to begin with. It gets from time to time discussed to deprecate them in Schema.org. I’d only use them in very [specific/rare cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867175/1591669).)