# How to create SiteNavigationElement using JSON-LD?

Tags: navigation, schema.org, json-ld

I'm trying to use the `SiteNavigationElement` type from Schema.org. The HTML is generated dynamically so I can't edit it. So JSON-LD is my only option.

I want all navigation elements under a single `SiteNavigationElement` object.

I have attached the desired output as screenshot:

[image: Desired structure output]

Comment: Related questions: [What is the correct use of schema.org SiteNavigationElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12491102/1591669) · [HTML image map as SiteNavigationElement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32084978/1591669) · [schema.org: SiteNavigationElement with multiple elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35316436/1591669)

Comment: @unor All related links creating schema using html. I have created other elements using json-ld and only i ma facing issue in `SIteNavigationElement`.

Comment: You did not describe where your problem is with implementing it in JSON-LD. --- I linked the related questions because these are about using `SiteNavigationElement` in an incorrect way; for this issue it doesn’t matter which syntax is used (Microdata, RDFa, JSON-LD), the error is one level higher. --- I reverted your edit because your question does not seem to be about Microdata nor Rich Snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Schema.org’s [`SiteNavigationElement` type](http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement) cannot be used for the navigation links, only for the whole navigation.

So the `url` would be the URL for the navigation (it typically doesn’t have one) and the `name` would be the name of the navigation (e.g., "Navigation" or "Main menu" etc.).

The type `SiteNavigationElement` (as well as the parent `WebPageElement` type and its other sub-types) is not really useful for typical web pages.

Comment: thanks for response. As per requirement i have to create this structure and that can be achieved by editing static html but in my case i can't. Those links are footer links. 'Header' denotes footer column heading name and name, URL represents their  respective children.

Comment: Did you understand my answer, i.e. that your intended use of `SiteNavigationElement` is not correct, but you want to do it anyway? -- If that’s the case, you need to provide more details in your question where exactly your problem is. But note that consumers (like Google) will most likely not understand your data correctly.

Comment: I got your point. Assume i have four professional service on same page and have to form schema using json-ld. I have created and it's validated by google. Problem is i need all services inside single professional service object in the form of inside @professionalDescripton -> name, description pairs. But i am getting different professional service object. https://jpst.it/JKZF  json code and can be checked here. https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: @krishnaisdinesh: I’m not sure I understand exactly what you want to achieve. If you have four professional services, you *have* to use four different `ProfessionalService` objects. With JSON-LD’s `@graph` you could provide these 4 objects in the same `script` element ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30506476/1591669)), if that is what you want. (By the way, note that [`ProfessionalService`](http://schema.org/ProfessionalService) got deprecated.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@graph":
    [
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
        "@id":"#table-of-contents",
        "name": "Section 1",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/page#toc-1"
      },
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
        "@id":"#table-of-contents",
        "name": "Section 2",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/page#toc-2"
      },
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
        "@id":"#table-of-contents",
        "name": "Section 3",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/page#toc-3"
      },
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
        "@id":"#pagination",
        "name": "Previous page",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/page1"
      },
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type":"SiteNavigationElement",
        "@id":"#pagination",
        "name": "Next page",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/page2"
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
```

This code will come out like as seen in [this example](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JayHoltslander/Structured-Data-JSON-LD/master/SiteNavigationElement.json#url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FJayHoltslander%2FStructured-Data-JSON-LD%2Fmaster%2FSiteNavigationElement.json).