# Error in SDTT: "SiteNavigationElement is not a known valid target type for the additionalType property."

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I tried a simple example, but the `SiteNavigationElement` is not working when I test it using the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/). It gives the error:

> `SiteNavigationElement` is not a known valid target type for the `additionalType` property.

The Microdata:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPageElement">
  <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/ItemList" />
  <meta itemprop="name" content="navigation_menu" />
  <ul>

    <li itemprop="additionalType" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
      <span itemprop="itemListElement">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/link_1" itemprop="url">
          <span itemprop="name">Link 1</span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </li>

    <li itemprop="additionalType" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
      <span itemprop="itemListElement">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/link_2" itemprop="url">
          <span itemprop="name">Link 2</span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `additionalType` property should not be used to create another item (which you are doing with `itemscope`+`itemtype`). Its job is to provide the URI of additional types, so the URI itself is the value here.

It seems that you want to mark up each link in your navigation. This is not possible with `SiteNavigationElement` (it [can only be used to mark up the whole navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133880/1591669), so it’s [typically useless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867175/1591669)).

It would be possible with `ItemList`, and you could provide `SiteNavigationElement` as `additionalType` (but I wouldn’t expect any consumer to make use of this):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
  <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" />
  <ul>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
      <a href="/link-1" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Link 1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
      <a href="/link-2" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Link 2</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or as an actual MTE (without `additionalType`):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
  <ul>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
      <a href="/link-1" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Link 1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
      <a href="/link-2" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Link 2</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as the MTE example above by @unor, except in JSON-LD. 
*(If your list has id's it makes sense to use them.)*

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":["ItemList", "SiteNavigationElement"],
  "@id": "https://example.com/#nav",
  "url":"https://example.com/#nav",
  "itemListElement":[
    {
      "@type":"WebPage",
      "position":1,
      "name": "home",
      "@id": "https://example.com/#home",
      "url":"https://example.com/home.html"
    },
    {
      "@type":"WebPage",
      "position":2,
      "name": "Core Solutions",
      "@id": "https://example.com/#core",
      "url":"https://example.com/core.html"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```